# Configure prerender io for Angularjs app running on IIS

Tags: angularjs, iis, seo, prerender

I have developed a angular js web app and hosted in the IIS server. My web app developed only by using javascript, css and html. But the problem is my web pages are not crawlers on the Google search. I have set the meta tags using javascript for each pages.

Can any one please explain me how to configure prerender middleware for IIS hosted web site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to want to use Prerender to cache your pages on its website, it caches html snapshots and then sends those to google for google to use during SEO, now, you say you've already got your meta tags done on each page, this means you can go right ahead and get prerender set up for angular, I'd recommend [this awesome tutorial scotch made](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-seo-with-prerender-io) on getting setup with prerender while using angularJS.

Comment: My site is hosted in IIS server, is this solution work on IIS? As I feel I need to host in on node js server.

Comment: This solution can work for IIS, I suggest you tag the question with "prerender" so as to allow the prerender staff to also reply to this question